# Where and how runtime error logs are saved in Android device?

Tags: android

While debugging, Log.d() or Log.e() methods come to LogCat, but how do I capture the runtime error or trace log on the Android device when it is not connected to the development environment ?

Comment: I have a strong feeling that you cannot :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works only for rooted phones...They work by executing `logcat` utility and capturing the `stdout` (`OutputStream`). But to execute the `logcat` utility, you need root rights....

There are more utilities, but here's a sample from `OpenIntents`...

[Logcat reader](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#1F2cuz7z7sk/trunk/samples/logcat/src/org/openintents/tools/logcat/LogcatProcessor.java&q=logcat%20package%3ahttp://openintents%5C.googlecode%5C.com&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc)

Answer (score 0):

It is not saved in your android device when adb is not connected to the developent environment, but you can save your runtime logs in a file

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and its working for me:: :)

To get the trace/issue logs user has to follow below steps:

1) First, user will be needing to DOWNLOAD AND INSTALL Google Android SDK program along with the Android USB drivers. User can download the Android SDK drivers from here :

"http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html" ( To get started, download the appropriate package from the table above, then read the guide to Installing the SDK :

"http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html")  and USB drivers for Windows operating system from here :  "http://dl.google.com/android/android_usb_windows.zip".

Installed the Android SDK to PC if not available.

2) Connect the Android device to the PC using USB.

3) Open the Command Prompt ( Terminal on MAC ) and go to the SDK/tools path on prompt (e.g. xyz-Devlop:tools username$, on my mac machine), then execute the

"./adb logcat" on MAC and "adb logcat" on Windows, command on Command Prompt (e.g. xyz-Devlop:tools username$ ./adb logcat, on my mac machine).

4) Run the application on device.

Logs will be then available in the Command Prompt/Terminal.

Enjoy Coding/Debugging......  :)

Comment: I don't think that your post answers the question -even though it might be working...